# Почему запятые перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция, запятая-перед-тире, запятая-и-тире

Sharon недавно вставила в один из ответов [ссылку](https://studopedia.ru/13_26981_g-sintaksicheskoe-vklyuchenie.html), из-за чего возник вопрос.

Почему запятые стоят перед обоими тире вставки?

> Я вправе ждать от тебя, – хотя бы сегодня, когда ты стоишь на пороге смерти, – немножко почтительности.

Там сказано, что вставки могут выделяться сложным знаком, а именно «, —».

На каком основании могут? С чего вдруг? В справочнике Розенталя сказано, что запятые и тире при вставках ставятся на *разных* основаниях.

А здесь же пишут, что выделяется *единым знаком*. С чего вдруг-то? Что-нибудь знаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Я вправе ждать от тебя, – **хотя бы сегодня, когда ты стоишь на пороге смерти,** – немножко почтительности.*

На месте вставки не было знаков, поэтому используем **два тире.**

(1) **Как вариант.**

Запятые относятся к вставке. **Первая запятая** относится к обороту ***хотя бы сегодня***. **Вторая запятая** закрывает придаточное.

Вставка **симметричная,** интонационно и графически никуда **не смещена**.

(2) **Единый знак?**

Графически это сочетание двух знаков. Можно сказать, что для обособления вставки используются не два тире, а два **единых знака** ввиду ее распространенности.

**Только тире?**

В принципе можно и тире обойтись: *Я вправе ждать от тебя – **хотя бы сегодня, когда ты стоишь на пороге смерти** – немножко почтительности.*

**ВЫВОД**

Вариант с тире выглядит **лучше других.** Зачем нам лишние знаки, если вставка симметричная.

Comment: Странно, что обособляется придаточное, которое фактически не считается членом предложения...

Comment: Интересное дело, вот у Розенталя: запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию.

Comment: М-да. Хотел получить ответ, а получил ещë больше вопросов.

Comment: Какие вопросы?  Два тире берите, хороший знак!  Это я просто рассматривала альтернативные варианты)

Comment: Ой, извините, дополнение не заметил.